# setup prerender.io to output only error messages from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, prerender

I've managed to switch on logging for prerender.io for the PhantomJS browser, using the `logger` plugin.  However, I would like only error messages to be logged.  The `logger` plugin logs just everything.  Based on the below pages:

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html
http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html

PhantomJS should have an `onError` event which is triggered when an error occurred.  Before trying to create a plugin, I've tried temporarily to update `server.js` of prerender.io, to attach to the `onError` event.  I've updated both `server.createPage` function as below, to attach to `page.onError` and even tried `page.set('onError')`, similar to the code found in the `logger.js`

```
server.createPage = function(req, res) {
    var _this = this;

    if(!this.phantom) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            _this.createPage(req, res);
        }, 50);
    } else {
        req.prerender.phantomId = this.phantom.id;
        this.phantom.createPage(function(page){
            req.prerender.page = page;
            console.log("registering onError for page");
            page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
                                                              var msgStack = ['PAGE PHANTOM ERROR OCCURRED: ' + msg];
                                                              msgStack.push('----------------------------------');
                                                              if (trace && trace.length) {
                                                                msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                                                                trace.forEach(function(t) {
                                                                  msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
                                                                });
                                                              }
                                                              msgStack.push('==================================');
                                                              console.log(msgStack.join('\n'));
                                                            };

            page.set('onError', function(msg, trace) {
                                                              var msgStack = ['PAGE2 PHANTOM ERROR OCCURRED: ' + msg];
                                                              msgStack.push('----------------------------------');
                                                              if (trace && trace.length) {
                                                                msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                                                                trace.forEach(function(t) {
                                                                  msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
                                                                });
                                                              }
                                                              msgStack.push('==================================');
                                                              console.log(msgStack.join('\n'));
                                                            });                                                         



            _this.onPhantomPageCreate(req, res);
        });
    }
};
```

I've also updated the `server.onPhantomCreate()`, method to attach to the general `phantom.onError`, as per below:

```
server.onPhantomCreate = function(phantom) {
    util.log('started phantom');
    this.phantom = phantom;
    this.phantom.id = Math.random().toString(36);
    console.log("Registering phantom.onError");
    phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
                                                              var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR OCCURRED: ' + msg];
                                                              msgStack.push('----------------------------------');
                                                              if (trace && trace.length) {
                                                                msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                                                                trace.forEach(function(t) {
                                                                  msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
                                                                });
                                                              }
                                                              msgStack.push('==================================');
                                                              console.log(msgStack.join('\n'));
                                                            };
    phantom.set('onError', function(msg, trace) {
                                                              var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR OCCURRED: ' + msg];
                                                              msgStack.push('----------------------------------');
                                                              if (trace && trace.length) {
                                                                msgStack.push('TRACE:');
                                                                trace.forEach(function(t) {
                                                                  msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function ' + t.function +')' : ''));
                                                                });
                                                              }
                                                              msgStack.push('==================================');
                                                              console.log(msgStack.join('\n'));
                                                            });


};
```

However, nothing is being logged.  Any ideas why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `onStdout` and `onStderr` functions through with the prerender options object:

```
var server = prerender({
    workers: 1,
    iterations: 50,
    onStdout: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    onStderr: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

You can't put onError on phantom directly because it isn't a real phantom instance, it's a node pipeline to the real phantomjs instance.

Comment: This throws a `dest.on is not a function` error from phridge

Comment: Sorry this probably only worked on an old version of our code. Try using our new Chrome rendering on our latest Prerender server!

Comment: I'm hosting Prerender on an AWS EC instance. Thanks for the great product anyway! :)